# LinkedIn API: The token used in the request has been revoked by the user

Tags: linkedin-api

We have integrated LinkedIn for the automation using OAuth2.0 3-legged authentication method. It was working fine earlier but now, our users are getting the following issue:

"The token used in the request has been revoked by the user"

**Issue Details:**
Our code, programmatically generates a new access token for the authenticated user with using the refresh token and when it gets fired in the next API call, our users are getting the above error. But, it starts working after 3 to 5 min.

**Note:** Our system uses refresh token to get the access token in each API call of the LinkedIn endpoint.

Error:

`{ "serviceErrorCode": 65601, "message": "The token used in the request has been revoked by the user", "status": 401 }`

Kindly, look into this matter and provide a quick solution except the delay after generating the token.

Comment: Did you find the reason ?, I get this error too.

Comment: Getting this issue as well. Thought it was something wrong on my end but looks like it might not be

Comment: I think I was able to get it to work by setting a timeout after refreshing the token, kind of hacky but I'm not sure what else to try

Comment: @stor314, you mean this may be related to eventual consistency on LI side? What was the duration of the timeout?

Comment: @RicardoSouza i think i set it to 5 seconds, after doing that never ran into the issue again. refresh only happens every two months so i just decided to leave it in

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling across this, the solution is to pass all values as URL parameters e.g.

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=...&client_id=...&client_secret=...
```

I had the same issue when using Go with the `golang.org/x/oauth2/endpoints` package as follows:

```golang
conf := &oauth2.Config{
    ClientID:     "LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID",
    ClientSecret: "LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET",
    Endpoint:     endpoints.LinkedIn,
}

ts := conf.TokenSource(context.Background(), token) // returns "revoked" tokens
```

Changing to this fixed it:

```golang
conf := &oauth2.Config{
    ClientID:     "LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID",
    ClientSecret: "LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET",
    Endpoint: oauth2.Endpoint{
        AuthURL:   "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization",
        TokenURL:  "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken",
        AuthStyle: oauth2.AuthStyleInParams, // this is the fix
    },
}

ts := conf.TokenSource(context.Background(), token)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use newly created LinkedIn connection throughout your workflow(s) and LinkedIn action steps. Delete all the previous LinkedIn connections and keep using the newly created connection. The LinkedIn connection will work for an year this means that and you only need to re-authorize your LinkedIn application in your Pabbly Connect workflows after an year.

Read more: https://forum.pabbly.com/threads/troubleshooting-linkedin.2023/